# While i am executing python scripts with pytest in pycharm it is not showing test cases numbers in test results tab

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

[image: Screenshot for output]

Is there any settings we need to do to see the test case number in test results tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering for "failed tests only", and all your tests seem to currently succeed.

Turn "Show Passed" on and you're good to go.

[image]